# How to query labels in Xcode UI testing

Tags: xcode-ui-testing

I see I can query textfields, tables, buttons, but not labels, why?

```
app.textFields["Username"].typeText("bcyops")
app.secureTextFields["Password"].typeText("ops15")
app.buttons["Submit"].tap()
app.tabBars.buttons["Main"].tap()
let tablesQuery = app.tables
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Labels are referred to as `staticTexts` in XCTest UI testing.

```
app.staticTexts["myLabel"].exists
```

Answer (score 5):

If you mean label as static text element, you can query label:

```
let label = app.staticTexts["yourLabelIdentifier"]
```

If you need a text in the label

```
let textInLabel = app.staticTexts["yourLabelIdentifier"].label
```

documentation with all elements types is here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementtypequeryprovider

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NSPredicates](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspredicate) to query elements with specified labels:

```
app.textViews.element(matching: NSPredicate(format: "label LIKE theLabelYoureLookingFor"))
```